# Merge Cells in LaTex

Tags: tables

How to make a table like this? I have tried many ways to do it but all are failed. I am so confused.
Thank you so much for any reply.
[image]

Comment: You should include a minimal working example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) with your question. What have you tried? Take a look at `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`

Comment: For the rules: `\usepackage{booktabs}` the first rule is `\toprule`, the second `\midrule`, then `\cmidrule{2-8}`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule{2-8}` and `\bottomrule`.

Comment: Also, while `\multirow` is an option, most of the time it only makes things more complicated. In your header, you can use `\makecell` (from the eponymous package) for those which need two rows. The things from columns 1 and 2 I'd just top align.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, I am newer to LaTex, could you please give a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I'd recreate your table (but with top-aligned contents for the columns 1 and 2).

I use `booktabs` for the rules, `siunitx` for the `S`-type columns which nicely align numbers, `amsmath` is just loaded for `\boldsymbol` to get a bold `>`, and I defined a macro for the table headers myself, to format all of them the same way (you could've used `makecell` and its `\thead` here as well).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\newcommand\myhead[1]{\myheadset\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand\myheadset{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccS[table-format=3]*{4}{S[table-format=1]}}
  \toprule
  \myhead{Type} & & & {\myhead{DF}} & {\myhead{Sum of\\Squares}}
    & {\myhead{Mean\\Squares}} & {\myhead{F Value}}
    & {\myhead{Prob$\boldsymbol{>}$F}} \\
  \midrule
  \myhead{City} & \myhead{Overall} & \myhead{Model} & 9 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \myhead{Group} & \myhead{ANOVA} & \myhead{Error} & 180 & 1 & 1 & & \\
  &&\myhead{Total} & 189 & 1 & & & \\
  \cmidrule{2-8}
  &\myhead{Levene's Test} & \myhead{Model} & 9 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  &&\myhead{Error} & 180 & 1 & 1 & & \\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \myhead{Year} & \myhead{Overall} & \myhead{Model} & 18 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \myhead{Group} & \myhead{ANOVA} & \myhead{Error} & 171 & 7 & 1 & & \\
  &&\myhead{Total} & 189 & 1 & & & \\
  \cmidrule{2-8}
  &\myhead{Levene's Test} & \myhead{Model} & 18 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  &&\myhead{Error} & 171 & 1 & 1 & & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]